# How to change one DIV field without affecting the others?

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, html, textfield

Small problem, I have a form in my Rails app with many fields, but all under the same field name as its a form right?

Code:

```
 <div class="field">
  <%= f.label :to %>
  <%= f.text_field :to, :class => 'address-picker-input' %>
 </div>
```

Now for some fields I want the form width to be shorter, what is the best way to customize each field individually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to customize each field individually, make a class for each field. But a good thing of CSS is that you can reuse it. So you can try to define some classes of fields.

Add another class:

```
<div class="field shorter">
```

and then on your css:

```
.field.shorter {
  width: 100px;
}
```